# Trigger CSS transition to anchor on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a simple problem that I don't know how to deal with it because I'm learning JavaScript

What I want to do is a link navigation to an anchor with fade in/out transition on CSS. For that, I must get the current page ID and the anchor href with JavaScript and trigger the CSS effect.

This is what I got so far:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  var next = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).parent().addClass('fadeout', function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
        }, 1000);
    $('#' + next).css('display', 'block');
    $('#' + next).addClass('fadein');
    });
});
```

```css
.fadeout {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.fadein {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

#page2,
#page3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page1">
  Page 1 Content
  <br>
  <a href="page2" class="btn">Show Page 2 and hide this page</a>
  <br>
  <a href="page3" class="btn">Show Page 3 and hide this page</a>
</div>

<div id="page2">
  Page 2 Content
  <br>
  <a href="page1" class="btn">Show Page 1 and hide this page</a>
  <br>
  <a href="page3" class="btn">Show Page 3 and hide this page</a>
</div>

<div id="page3">
  Page 3 Content
  <br>
  <a href="page1" class="btn">Show Page 1 and hide this page</a>
  <br>
  <a href="page2" class="btn">Show Page 2 and hide this page</a>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for helping me learning

Comment: Can you please explain what is your problem ? @Ermac

Comment: See the error in the Snippet, I can fade out my content, but I can't load the new one :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

- The `addClass` method just expects 1 parameter, so that second parameter (function) will never get called.
- The `this` inside your timeout callback is not what you think it is. `this` behaves somewhat strange, and can be hard to grasp, especially when you are just starting out with javascript. I won't explain it here (plenty of info out there), but I would cache the value inside a variable outside the timeout function in this case.
- You are adding classes on fadeout, but you are never removing them again when you fade back in. I would make sure that in you HTML all visible 'pages' have a class `fadein` and the invisible ones a class `fadeout`. That way you can just toggle both to switch the state.
- jQuery offers the `show()` and  `hide()` methods, so I would use those in stead of modifying the `display` value yourself.
- jQuery actually offers a `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` method as well, which are probably better suited here, but let's stick with you css animation here for sake of your "exercise".
- If you use a jQuery selector more then once, it is wise to put it inside a variable. That way the DOM parsing needs to be done only once. As your DOM becomes more complex, this is in fact quite a expensive operation.

So with that said, you javascript would look something like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $target = $(this);
  var $next = $('#' + $(this).attr('href'));
  $target.parent().toggleClass('fadeout fadein');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $target.parent().hide();
    $next.show();
    $next.toggleClass('fadein fadeout');
  }, 1000);
});
```

Have a look at the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/rr7a7sL4/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I learnt a lot with this =)